# What is pchCommand?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, terminology, block-header, compact-blocks

[BIP152](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0152.mediawiki) and [BIP130](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0130.mediawiki) are using this term. What does it mean? Command name in message header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `pchCommand` is the name of the variable for the message name in the network message header.

The naming of this variable uses [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). `p` indicates it is a pointer, `ch` indicates that it is char(s), and the variable name begins with an uppercase. So the type for this variable is a pointer to chars, which is a string. Bitcoin Core no longer actively uses this notation, although it is still around in things that Satoshi wrote originally, which `pchCommand` is.